# Can't see all settings in Package/Publish Web project properties in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish, msdeploy

For some reason I can't see all of the settings in the Package/Publish Web project properties in VS 2012 Update 2.  AFAIK this just started happening.  Has anyone run across this?

This is what I currently see:
[image]

This is what I should be seeing:
[image]

Notice that I can't see the web deployment package settings.

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Right click on your project, then click _Publish_. You'll see more options in the wizard.

Comment: That allows me to publish but doesn't solve the problem....

Comment: Create a new profile and choose `Web Deploy Package` in the second step. You'll be presented with the options you were missing.

Comment: So @AlexFilipovici you were right.  That is by design.  They actually removed those settings from the project properties: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792675/cant-see-all-settings-in-package-publish-web-project-properties-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it turns out that @AlexFilipovici was correct in his comments.  In Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 they removed those settings from the Package/Publish Web project settings.  They are only included in the Publish dialog and meant to be stored in a publish profile:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792675/cant-see-all-settings-in-package-publish-web-project-properties-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2